# Pivoting multiple columns in R similar to Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I want to pivot a dataframe in R similar to what Pandas does below.

**Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
trials = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4], 
                       'treatment':['A','A', 'B', 'B'],
                       'gender' :['F','M', 'F', 'M'], 
                       'response':[5,3,8,9]}
                      )

trials.pivot(index= 'treatment', columns='gender')
```

Gives the result below:

[image]

Comment: check with ftable ?

Comment: Check out `spread` from `tidyr`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added data.table and CRAN-version tidyr solutions

1. `tidyr` 0.8 from CRAN is a little unwieldy since you have to combine the two headers (gender and whether the value is `id` or `response`) manually and then spread:

   ```
   library(tidyr)
   trials %>%
     gather(column, value, -c(treatment, gender)) %>%
     unite(header, column, gender) %>%
     spread(header, value)

   #  treatment id_F id_M response_F response_M
   #1         A    1    2          5          3
   #2         B    3    4          8          9
   ```
2. The development version of `tidyr` makes this a little easier with the new `pivot_wider` function:

   ```
   # devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")
   library(tidyr) # Need current development version, as pivot_wider
                  #  not in CRAN release yet. Using 0.8.99.9000 here.
   pivot_wider(trials, names_from = gender, values_from = c(id, response))    

   ## A tibble: 2 x 5
   #treatment  id_F  id_M response_F response_M
   #<chr>     <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
   #1 A             1     2          5          3
   #2 B             3     4          8          9
   ```
3. `data.table` also makes this straightforward:

   ```
   library(data.table)
   dcast(setDT(trials), treatment ~ gender, value.var = c("id", "response"))
   #   treatment id_F id_M response_F response_M
   #1:         A    1    2          5          3
   #2:         B    3    4          8          9
   ```

Comment: Is the issue that you want multi-row headers for the data? I'm not aware of a natural way to do that in R, though there are many packages for reporting which let you create an output format with multi-row headers that span multiple columns.

Comment: Here's an example: https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_spanner.html   But I'm not aware of a data structure in R that would allow this sort of thing natively.

Comment: It's interesting that you want it like that.  One of my biggest issues with pandas coming from R is that it's always indexing things.